# kotlin coroutines: possible without standard library?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

My question is rather theoretical.
I am quite new to kotlin (only passed the tutorial, didn't write any real code).

Reading through the language reference I find myself confused about the fact that "suspend" is a keyword, yet I can't find anything like "launch" in the list of keywords. That makes me think that there is some asymmetry - the "suspend" is a compiler feature, yet "launch" is a library function. Is my understanding correct? If so - wouldn't it have been better to implement both as library features or both as compiler features?

I always thought that you can always write your own standard library using the available language features, but I still can't see if this really applies to this case.

**TL;DR:** Can I start a coroutine using pure kotlin, without importing any libraries whatsoever (however ugly that would be)?

Comment: have you tried going thru `kotlinx.coroutines` (I assume that's what you want to replace for some reason?) and seeing how it's done?

Comment: Yes, I did. If you trace it down, then you end up with something like SafeContinuation::resumeWith() (for which I didn't find the sources).
However, this is not what my question is about. My question is why "launch" is a library function and "suspend" is a keyword? Why this asymmetry?

Comment: You could ask on official kotlin forum or coroutines github to have better chance of catching attention of someone that actually made that decision. My guess is including `suspend` as a standard keyword is just a little "cheat" from developers team because otherwise they'd need to resort to weird marker annotations.

Comment: I seem to have found some implementation that might be related:
coroutineCodegenUtil.kt contains an implementation of invokeDoResumeWithUnit() which contains a couple of stack interactions and an invokevirtual(). My guess is that these are translated directly into corresponding bytecodes.
If kotlin gives us ability to generate byte codes directly then I am even more confused about why "suspend" is not a library function but a keyword.

But thank you for the pointer, that really seems like the way to go.

Comment: Judging but what is said in "Kotlin Coroutines Reloaded", the compiler support is not limited to the "suspend" keyword. There seems to be also "start coroutine" and "suspend coroutine" functionality.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2440&v=3xalVUY69Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I start a coroutine using pure kotlin, without importing any libraries whatsoever (however ugly that would be)?

No. All coroutine generators are inside `kotlinx.coroutines` library, so you'll need at least that. Now, very theoretically, you could reimplement this functionality yourself. But probably you shouldn't.

How this can be done is a bit too long for a StackOverflow answer, but try invoking method of this Kotlin class from Java:

```
class AsyncWorks {
    suspend fun print() {
        println("Hello")
    }
}
```

You'll see that although Kotlin method has no arguments, in Java it requires `Continuation<? super Unit>`. This is what `suspend` keyword does. It adds `Continuation<T>` as the last argument of our function.

> wouldn't it have been better to implement both as library features or
>   both as compiler features?

Ideally, you'd want everything to be a "library feature", since it's easier to evolve. Removing a keyword from a language is very hard. In theory, having `suspend` as a keyword could be avoided. [Quasar](https://github.com/puniverse/quasar), being a framework, uses annotations instead. Go programming language, on the other hand, assumes all functions are suspendable. All those approaches have their advantages and disadvantages.
Kotlin decided to be pragmatic, and add `suspend` keyword, leaving the decision on the developers. If you're interested in the topic, I highly recommend this talk by Roman Elizarov, author of Kotlin coroutines, that explains their decissions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mj5P47F6nJg

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You can use coroutines and suspend code all without the coroutines library. The library is just a bunch of nice helper functions and other abstractions (e.g. flow) built on the compilers coroutine support. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 4):

@Alexey Soshin's isn't quite correct.

You can use coroutines w/o the library, and it's pretty easy. Here is a about the simplest suspending coroutine example that has 0 dependency on the coroutine library.

```
import kotlin.coroutines.*

fun main() {

    lateinit var context: Continuation<Unit>
    
        suspend {
            val extra="extra"
            println("before suspend $extra")
            suspendCoroutine<Unit> { context = it }
            println("after suspend $extra")
        }.startCoroutine(
            object : Continuation<Unit> {
                override val context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
                // called when a coroutine ends. do nothing.
                override fun resumeWith(result: Result<Unit>) {
                    result.onFailure { ex : Throwable -> throw ex }
                }
            }
        )
    
        println("kick it")
        context.resume(Unit)
}
```

This runs fine on the play.kotlinlang.org site.

As you can see from this code, any lambda decorated with `suspend` has the `startCourtine()` on it.

In fact, I think the `SequenceBuilder()` from the standard collection classes uses a simple coroutine like this to generate the sequence, with no dependency on the coroutine library.

The compiler is doing the heavy lifting on the coroutines, splitting the code into different "methods" at each possible suspending point. Look at the java code for this, and you'll see it's "split" into a switch statement. one case before the suspend, and another after.

The library does a ton of nice stuff for you..... and it's likely you'll almost always use it (cuz why not?) but you don't actually need it.

Comment: Thank you, @West_JR. Your answer helped me a lot, I was able to move further with it! Yet, the question was if it is possible without *standard* library. Since you have `import`, you are still falling short of this goal.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. I do not use the coroutines library. All that stuff, flows and channels and launchers etc are all in kotlinx.* which I am not importing.
I do use the standard library... which is basically the kotlin run-time. I'm unaware of any kotlin app of any size that can run w/o the standard library. Even if you don't explicitly import it, "Int" & "String" are all in the standard library, as well as how main() gets launched.

Comment: Perhaps my expectations are wrong. I generally imagine a compiler as the base layer. That should be so in every language - be it Kotlin or Java or C or anything else. The standard library is written in a language that compiler understands. For *performance reasons* some parts might be written in a more low-level language, but that should be optional. Upon the standard library everything else is built. Therefore if compiler is aware of the standard library then this is a breach of abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

The `suspend` marker adds a hidden continuation parameter to the function signature and completely changes the implementation bytecode. Suspension points don't boil down to helper function calls, they turn your linear program code into a state machine, the state being kept in the continuation object. The resulting bytecode isn't even representable as Java program code.

As opposed to that, `launch` is just regular library code that builds upon the suspend/resume primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here.

After a year of Kotlin I tend to think that this IS indeed possible.
The `suspend` language feature creates an extra class and instantiates it every time your suspend function is called. This class extends `ContinuationImpl` and stores the progress of your coroutine - to which point it was able to execute so far.

Therefore one will need to write a custom dispatcher that would be able to manage the queue of the continuation objects to decide which one has to run now and a `launch` function that would take the newly created continuation object and pass it over to the dispatcher.

Now, this is still an asymmetry - the `ContinuationImpl` lives in `kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal` so the compiler assumes this package exists. If one really wants to drop the standard library altogether - he'll need to implement that package to be able use the `suspend` keyword.

I'm not a kotlin expert though, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because coroutines are valid for use cases that [*don't support* launch](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html).  Because `suspend` requires some [specific support from the compiler](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#compiling-suspending-functions) and `launch` *doesn't* if you already have `suspend`.  Because structured concurrency is a [library framework](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) on top of the language feature, and `launch` is a part of that specific framework, that makes specific choices on top of what the language requires.

Starting a coroutine without any libraries can be done with [`startCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/start-coroutine.html).  `kotlin.coroutines` is part of Kotlin, not a library.